# Regex preg_match not working as expected

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So Im taking links from database and those looks like this:

```
www.website.com/games/randomcode1/RANDOM-URL-TITLE-NEEDED.html
www.website.com/blabla/randomcode2/RANDOM-URL-TITLE-NEEDED2.htm
www.website.com/whatever/randomcode2/RANDOM-URL-TITLE-NEEDED3.html
```

In my foreach loop Urls are represented as `$row['links'];`
what Im trying to do is to take only RANDOM-URL-TITLE-NEED. That means I need text in the url from last slash (after randomcode) till the end of URL.
Im using this preg match function to take what I need but It seems Im failing with regerx at the begining(?). Any advices:

```
preg_match('#/(?:.*?).htm#is', $row['links'], $vardas);
$vardas = $vardas[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually match the first `/` and then any 1+ chars up to the first `htm`.

I believe you need

```
#/([^/]*)\.html?$#i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sR9cS8/1)

*Details*:

- `/` - a literal `/`
- `([^/]*)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ chars other than `/`
- `\.` - a literal `.`
- `html?` - `html` or `htm`
- `$` - end of string

A variation of the pattern for `preg_filter` (in case you pass an array of strings):

```
$urls = array("www.website.com/games/RANDOM-URL-TITLE-NOT_NEEDED.xhtml",
    "www.website.com/games/randomcode1/RANDOM-URL-TITLE-NEEDED.html",
    "www.website.com/blabla/randomcode2/RANDOM-URL-TITLE-NEEDED2.htm",
    "www.website.com/whatever/randomcode2/RANDOM-URL-TITLE-NEEDED3.html");

print_r(preg_filter('#^.*/(.*)\.html?$#i', '$1', $urls));
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/zBFm3G), only returning

```
[1] => RANDOM-URL-TITLE-NEEDED
[2] => RANDOM-URL-TITLE-NEEDED2
[3] => RANDOM-URL-TITLE-NEEDED3
```

The updated regex pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*/` - 0+ chars other than a newline as many as possible up to the last `/` and the slash itself
- `(.*)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars other than newline as many as possible up to the last
- `\.html?` - `.htm` or `.html` substrings at...
- `$` - the end of the string.

The `$1` is a backreference to the value captured into Group 1.

Comment: I see, I added the explanation for the updated regex used inside the `preg_filter`.

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant way without using Regular Expressions:

```
echo pathinfo($url)['filename'];
```